# How to update binutils to get the security patches on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I tried to update the binutils via auto update script but it is not updating on it's own so can someone help me on this request.

Regards,
Neelesh Tiwari

Comment: Easy: Install Ubuntu 20.04. Please see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 has passed its End-of-life date, and is no longer supported on AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about security, use an up-to-date and supported distribution. 16.04 went out of support in April this year. There are no more updates for that release.

Updating only the binutils is really trying to cure the symptom, not the cause.